# how to intercept(not only capture) outgoing packets from TCP programs(or specifically TCP stack)?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a web server running on a host and I want to intercept all packets(including IP/TCP header) sent by the webserver, so the packets are not sent out to the Internet by the web server directly.

Originally, my plan is to use iptables to filter out the packets sent by the web server
and use libpcap to capture the packets. But I got to know the packet  flow is:

```
  Wire----NIC----libpcap----INPUT CHAIN---TCP STACK
  Wire----NIC----libpcap----OUTPUT CHAIN---TCP STACK
```

this means for incoming packets, I can use libpcap and iptables to implement the interception: use libpcap to capture packets and iptables to prevent the packets from delivering to TCP stack.  But for intercepting outgoing packets from web server, the combination of libpcap and iptables seems not to work. Because if I filter the outgoing packets, my libpcap can't capture these packets. If I don't use iptables to filter, although I can capture the packets using libpcap, the original packets will reach the Internet.

My target is to intercept all the packets(including TCP/IP header) sent from the webserver，are there any  solutions? thanks!

Note:  I'm not asking on how to modifying the packets TCP/IP header, I just let you know that why I want to intercept packets(including IP/TCP header). I'm asking on how to intercept packets.

Comment: Why? What *actual, practical problem* are you trying to solve here?

Comment: You should be more specific in what you end goal is, you are asking how to perform a method, "modify tcp headers" but not the aim. Try and explain more about your objective here.

Comment: @user138126 You are still not articulating an *actual* ***practical*** problem that you are trying to solve. You want to do something, but you are not telling us ***WHY***.  ***WHY*** is important - it is the difference between the answer being "Don't do that, it's ridiculously stupid and there's no reason for it." and "You can do `X` to achieve your goal." (Right now I'm leaning toward the first option -- absent a *good reason* what you're asking to do is pretty insane...)

Comment: I'm doing a research work, my advisor asked me to construct a system. It is a very long story.  So I just put my question straightforward. I want to intercept the packets from the webserver. And then I need to modify the IP header of the packets and send them out to Internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using libpcap to grab the packet for modifications is the wrong tool.  You should almost certainly be looking at one of the methods built into netfilter for handling packets in user-space.

If you want to modify or abuse the packets in ways not already built into netfilter, then you might want to take a strong look at the NFQUEUE target.

This allow you to set up rules so that the packet is delivered to userspace.  You can then do whatever you want to it, and then re inject.

If you don't actually need to do anything to the packet other then accept it, then the ULOG target might provide what you want.  ULOG forwards the entire packet off to a user-space process for logging.

Of course your other option might be to build your own netfilter modules to make any unusual packet changes, if none of the built in methods provide what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You *probably* want to put a proxy such as nginx or haproxy in front of Apache.

This will make it possible to massage the response from Apache in the appropriate way and it'll be MUCH easier than doing it at the network level.

Comment: Agree 100%. If not that, you can just parse apache logs yourself for what is there you are looking for.

Comment: no,  I want to modify the IP header or even the TCP header after intercepting the packets. So proxy is not a solution. Note, I'm not asking on how to modifying the packets, I just let you know that why I want to intercept packets(including IP/TCP header).